# How write header with nestjs

Tags: header, nestjs

how I can write headers using way nest.js?

I'm currently using this:

```
import { Controller, Body, Get, Post, HttpCode, HttpStatus, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Usuario } from '../usuario/usuario.entity';
import { JsonWebTokenError } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { request } from 'http';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) { }

    @Post('login')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    async login(@Body('username') username: string, @Body('password') password: string, @Res() response: Response) {
        this.authService
            .validateUser(username, password)
            .then((token) => {
                response.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

                let respuesta: any = {};
                respuesta.success = true;
                respuesta.token = token;

                return response.send(respuesta);
            });
    }
}
```

I do not want to use `response.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);` and `return response.send(respuesta);`

**Thanks for your answers!**

Answer (score 7):

NestJS is build on top of express, so do it like in express:

```
async login(@Body('username') username: string, @Body('password') password: string, @Res() res: Response) {
    const token = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    res.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    res.send({
        success: true,
        token,
    })
});
```

Comment: Does this set HTTP Only though?

Answer (score 7):

In latest versions you could use the `@Header` decorator within NestJS Core.

```js
import { Controller, Get, Req, Header, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Controller('cookies')
export class CookiesController {
  @Get('set')
  // @Header('Set-Cookie', 'cookieName = 12345') // "Usin header decorator"
  setCookie(@Res() response: Response): Response {
    /*
    * If using express approach, pass @Res as param decorator
    */
    response.cookie('rememberme', '1') // Using express res object.
    return response.send('Cookie has been set! :)')
  }

  @Get()
  checkCookie(@Req() request: Request ): string {
    console.log(Object.keys(request.cookies))
    if(Object.keys(request.cookies).length > 0){
      console.log('cookies =>', request.cookies)
      return 'Cookies are set :)'
    } else {
      return 'Uh, oh! Cookie hasn\'t been set :\'('
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer did not provide a solution. The `Header` decorator is for **reading** a header and not setting it. Plus, your code example has it commented out.

Comment: @DoronG I have to object here, although I understand the confusion. There is a `@Header` decorator which sets _response_ headers, and it is used on controller methods. But there is also a `@Headers` (note the plural) decorator which can be used on controller method _parameters_, and that one will inject a request header as an argument. See https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#headers and https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object respectively

Comment: @manuhornung You are correct. I must admit I was confused. Thank you for the clarification. I have tried to change my vote, but can only do so if the original answer is edited. Can you edit your answer to clarify it as well?